# How to detect if something has been bought from Google Checkout from PHP?

Tags: php, google-checkout, web-applications

I am making a Web app that will be available in free and paid forms. I want to make it detect whether the user has paid for paid version using Google Checkout, and enable paid features if they have.

How would I do this in PHP?

**Update** I already have a user table in my database, and the user is required to log in to use the app. I will also create a table called **purchases** which will have the following:

- **userid** An internally used account id
- **chitchat** (the name of the app) NULL or a Google order id

Then when I need to detect if the user has bought it I would use

```
$userid=esc($_SESSION["id"]); // esc is a function that returns the SQL escaped string
if($query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE userid='$userid'")&&mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
    // The user has bought the paid version
}
```

But then, in case my server is hacked, how would I confirm the order id with Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the fact that you've shared very little information about your web app, it's difficult to answer with a precise answer but here are some pointers:

1. Create a database of users and require that people sign up.
2. When someone makes a purchase, note that in the database. During the Google checkout process, Google will let you know that a transaction was successful.
3. When a user signs in, check whether or not they've made a purchase and grant them permission to "paid-only" areas.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html should help you too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answers, Francois and esqew. My apologies that I didn't explain much in the question, but I've added more information. I will have a look at the information provided at the link above.

Comment: @Adam: Have a look at the [Order Report API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API.html#Sending_an_Order_Report_API_Request). Should you get hacked, which hopefully won't happen, you can request a list of all transactions between 2 dates from Google. The tricky part will be matching the transactions to users. My advice: backup your data daily!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will also have a look at that.